# jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

Tags: java, gradle, guice

My code:

```
for (Class<? extends Module> module : moduleClasses) {
            log.info("Module will config: {}", module);
                       // module like com.test.apps.hello.module.SomeModule
            try {
                install(module.newInstance());
                          log.info("Configured: {}", module.getName());
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {

                throw Throwables.propagate(e);
            }
        }

public class SomeModule extends Module {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(SomClass.class).to(SomClassImp.class);
    }
}
```

It is working fine when I try to install only few class, but when many class I got this problem:

> jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

I use gradle version 4.3.1.

I think the problem might be from gradle.

Comment: What are you doing? Compiling? Running your code? How?

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for quick response. I got this problem when running.

Comment: When running what? How?

Comment: First i use gradle build everything is ok. but when i use gradle init to initialize    and migrate database i got that problem. if i try to install(module.newInstance()); only few module it working find but many module together it have problem.

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes for one minute. We can't see your screen. We have no idea of what your gradle init task works. We have no idea of what a module is. At least post the command you execute and the exact and complete gradle output. It's hard to say if the code you post has any relevance to your question.

Comment: @SoPhatVathana I would be greatly helpful if you can specify the command line that you used (add `--debug` as well), along with the stacktrace output.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i can solve this problem by increase maximum size memory JVM (-Xmx1024m).

Answer (score 0):

Base on this error i could solve this problem by increase the maximum size memory JVM (-Xmx1024m).